# Dropping a build in a fixed location

Tags: tfs, build

I have a build process that I've defined with a custom build process template, and I'm looking for some advice on how I can solve a problem I've run up against.

The build process (TFS 2012) is used to build the code that drives our load tests, and I have a separate process that needs to reference a specific path within the drop folder so that it is always using the latest version of the load test code. Automated load testing, pretty standard stuff.

However, I'm wondering if there is a way to get the TFS build to overwrite files it finds in the drop folder. Right now I have it set up to drop to a very specific folder, and not put anything that would change in the folder name (no build number, date, etc.). The thought is, this way the automated utilities that rely on those files have a fixed point to look at.

However, when I currently run the build it gives me error `TF42064: The build number '<build>' already exists for build definition '<build>'.`

Currently I have the build definition set up to only retain the latest build, because this process is specifically for those automated tools. We have other build processes that are fired for debugging/troubleshooting/logging purposes. Is there a way to get the build definition to overwrite the drop folder each time, or will I have to dig into the .XAML template file to have it delete the folder it finds before the build fires?

Comment: You can edit the build-definition

Comment: How? I'm not seeing a way to do it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx#template_edit

Comment: That's editing the .XAML template file, not the build definition. But if that's the way I need to do it, I'll do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I approached this requirement was to start with the default template and let the build copy to the normal drop location which allows me to keep historical builds in the same way as all other builds.

Once the build has been completed I then copied to a single drop location from the standard drop location by extending the standard build template, the activity was added just before Check-In gated changes.

The steps involved were as follows:

- Within SharedResourceScope:

  - Delete Unified Drop Location
  - Create Unified Drop Location
  - Copy Directory (source: BuildDetail.DropLocation)

Answer (score 0):

By default TFS Build creates a new folder, using the unique build name/number, and drops the files there.

If you want to change this behaviour to overwrite files in a known location (instead of creating a new folder each build) you need to modify the build workflow/XAML (as @Oswald mentioned in the comments).

You can read about customizing TFS Builds from the ALM Ranger Build Guidance on CodePlex: http://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com/